# BILOU Tagging scheme for multi-word entities in Spacy's NER

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am working on building a custom NER using spacy for recognizing new entities apart from spacy's NER. Now I have my training data to be tagged and added using spacy.Example. I am using the BILOU scheme. My doubt is that I have entities which have more than 3 words. For example:

```
Housing Development Finance Corporation reported heavy losses in the past quarter.
```

I want to tag Housing Development Finance Corporation as a single Entity using the BILOU scheme. Something like

```
'Housing'     B-Entity
'Development' I-Entity
'Finance'     I-Entity
'Corporation' L-Entity
```

Is this tagging correct?How will the model interpret the order within each entity?Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at some example data in BILOU format for an idea of how things look. In particular words should not be quoted and every word - not just entities - needs a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tagging you have is correct while all outside words which are not entities would be marked with `O`.

The model will be depending on the same order within the entity to match it towards a previous entity of the same name, ex:

```
'Housing'     B-Entity
'Development' I-Entity
'Finance'     I-Entity
'Corporation' L-Entity
```

and

```
'Housing'     B-Entity
'Finance'     I-Entity
'Development' I-Entity
'Corporation' L-Entity
```

will not be linked as the same entity, although if you want this to be the case, you could look into a classification model to classify your foud entities towards your previously known entities and work from there.